# Create IPSec Pre-shared key VPN on Windows <> Cisco ASA

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I am trying to create a VPN tunnel between Windows 7 host computer and Cisco ASA firewall. For this I have been given details of VPN protocol and encryption by the company that owns the Cisco ASA:

[image]

I have created and assigned the IPSec policy settings with respective Encryption in Local Security Policy snap-in but how to establish the VPN tunnel? Should I add a VPN connection from network connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else bumps into this:

To create an IPSec tunnel with IKE protocol between Windows host* and a VPN service (Cisco ASA in my case) you have to set up a IP Security policy in Local Security Policy snap-in from your MMC. (or group policy if done in active directory environment) 
For exact steps on how to configure the key exchange and encryption process please refer to this [guide](http://www.slideshare.net/webhostingguy/configuring-windows-2000xp-ipsec-for-sitetosite-vpn) as it may vary depending on your exact VPN service.

*Note - windows is the endpoint of the VPN tunnel here, not a pass-through (routing) server/device. (although the guide shows you how to configure both)